# How do I get the menu bar to reappear

Tags: xfce, file-manager, thunar

This sound like a really simple thing, but it has me stumped. I was using Thunar file manager on my Xfce desktop and I wanted to try it without the menu bar at the top (the one with File, Edit, View and so on), so I disabled it through View > Menu Bar (or something similar).

After realising how much I use and rely on it, I wanted it back, but could not find an option anywhere to re-enable it. I tried using the Alt key and the file manager preferences, but couldn't find anything. Surely there's an option *somewhere*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut is shown in the View menu : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd forgotten to note the shortcut, and couldn't find it through searching.